# Passing variable of class from func to another func

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, netmiko

I am building a program using gui tkinter+netmiko. Now I have entry field, button 'Connect', button 'Run command'. It does what I need, prints an output of a command, but every time it uses connect func and initializes A connection to a remote device. It it possible to connect only once and use **net_connect** variable (it's a class) in other functions? So in **run_command** func I would only use returned value of the **connect**, but not to call the entire **connect** func.
I'll have dozens of **run_command** functions with different commands. As far as I understand here I cannot use global variables. I omitted the rest of the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def connect():
    Router = {'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'ip': hostname_entry.get(), 'username': 'x', 'password': 'x'}
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**Router)
    return net_connect

def run_command():
    command = connect()
    show_version_output = command.send_command('show version') # here I need to use: *show_version_output = net_connect.send_command*
    print(show_version_output)
    return show_version_output
```

Comment: One of the way is to move those functions into a class and use instance variables which can be accessed across class methods.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I believe that I'm not there yet with classes and stuff. There for to be a simpler solution!

Comment: If you don't know how to use class, then using global variables is the other way.

Comment: Well thank you, net_connect = 0 solves the promblem, even though pycharm warns me that send.command could not be integer value.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the `ssh_conn` as an argument:

```py
from tkinter import *
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

def connect():
    Router = {'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 'ip': hostname_entry.get(), 'username': 'x', 'password': 'x'}
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**Router)
    return net_connect

def run_command(ssh_conn, cmd):
    output = ssh_conn.send_command(cmd)
    print(output)
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ssh_conn = connect()
    show_ver = run_command(ssh_conn, cmd="show version")
    show_ip_int_br = run_command(ssh_conn, cmd="show ip int brief")
```